# How bad is batching ECC into distinct cohorts?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The actual problem concerns using redundant error-correcting blocks to protect a collection of data blocks against erasure.  Ideally, if I supplied $50\%$ additional blocks, I could tolerate $50\%$ loss of the original blocks (or $\frac13$ of the enlarged data set).  But, one ECC block does not substitute for *any* block of original, but only for those in the batch in which it was built.

Here is an abstract description:

Given $n$ urns each containing $j$ balls, each ball labeled with the $(n,j)$ it represents;

If you randomly take some fraction $p$ of the $n\cdot j$ balls, what is the probability that you took fraction $q$ or more of the balls from any one urn?

The balls are labeled so you can do a variation "with replacement" and record which ones were drawn.  Random damage may hit a block that was already damaged.

In the example of the introduction, $q = \frac13$.  If we also postulate $n=10$ and $j=15$, then as few as $6$ hits *could* damage a row beyond repair, which is a far cry from the $50\%$ ($50$ blocks) the user expected.

What is the *real* safety percentage against random damage?  Given some percentage of random hits, what is the probability that any one urn will have too many hits?

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the urns separately. If the probability that each single block is damaged is identically and independently distributed, then it will still be that way if you only look at a single urn. Calculate the probability that a set of $j$ blocks survives (i.e. can be reconstructed), if the probability of a block being damaged is $p$. Then using this probability, you can calculate the probability that all blocks survive by taking the result to the $n$th power.

Comment: Of course, if your errors aren't distributed that way (e.g. you have a certain probability of batch errors that affect several adjacent blocks), then you can't model it this way.

Comment: I think that is only true to some approximation: if one urn has more hits (to the point of being significatly higher than the overall average) then other urns necessarily have *less*.  So taking the probability of one group surviving and multiplying by the number of groups will not hold.

Comment: Re random distribution: that's a different problem. Understanding damage pattern in a particular use can help arrange things to best advantage, or just randomize block placement to counteract any such effects.